# transform.RotateAround

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, yRotation * Time.deltaTime);
```

Как мне сделать, чтоб вместо zero было относительно родителя?

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно получить мировые координаты родителя

```
transform.parent.position
```

а вот так локальные

```
transform.parent.localPosition
```

---

Вращение вокруг точки местонахождения родительского обьекта

```
transform.RotateAround(
    transform.parent.position,
    Vector3.up, 
    yRotation * Time.deltaTime
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Указывать позицию родителя в аргументах:

```
transform.RotateAround (transform.parent.position, transform.parent.up, yRotation * Time.deltaTime);
```